# Combining hot point mission and waypoint mission in DJI-Mobile-SDK(android)

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I have implemented the waypoint mission in android using DJI mobile sdk. 
Now I want the drone to hover around each waypoint when it reaches there, like a hotpoint mission, with the waypoint as the hot point, after hovering it should go to the next waypoint and do the same.

Is it possible to pause the waypoint mission when it reaches the waypoint and start the hot point mission?

Or this can be done using timeline? Can anyone shed some light on this? Cannot find proper solution in Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Mission Control" to do this. There is more than one way to do this. Read this here:
https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIMissionControl.html?search=missionc&i=0&

Answer (score 1):

As Amir pointed out you can use a timeline mission from mission control.

You will need to chain waypoint and hotpoint missions.
If you need simply one point between each hotpoint, use the [gotoaction](https://developer.dji.com/cn/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIGoToAction.html).

Stopping a waypoint mission while running a hotpoint is not an option.